# Redondeo de decimales en array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```js
var Array = [
    ["MAQUINA", "MIN"],
    ["CABINA EXTRACCION DISTANCIALES", 292.6333333333333],
    ["CPU6 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB SELLADO1 COMAU", 36.63333333333333],
    ["CPU10 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB HORNO ESM1 IZCOMAU", 30],
    ["CPU11 GR01 SG5 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
    ["CPU11 GR01 SG8 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
    ["CPU1 GR11 SG1 FLY ROLLER COMAU", 15],
    ["CPU2A MESA ENTRADA BONDER ABB", 12]
]
```

Estoy intentando redondear los valores que aparecen en decimales.

Utilicé el siguiente código pero no funciona. Supongo que es porque la primera columna es texto:

```js
Array = Array.map(function(each_element) {
    return Number(each_element.toFixed(2));
});
```

También probé:

```js
Array = Array.map(function(each_element) {
    return Math.round(each_element * 100) / 100;
});
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para redondear solo la segunda columna del arreglo o todos los valores que son solamente números?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías usar doble `map`:

```js
var Array =  [["MAQUINA", "MIN"],
    ["CABINA EXTRACCION DISTANCIALES", 292.6333333333333],
    ["CPU6 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB SELLADO1 COMAU", 36.63333333333333],
    ["CPU10 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB HORNO ESM1 IZCOMAU", 30],
    ["CPU11 GR01 SG5 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
    ["CPU11 GR01 SG8 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
    ["CPU1 GR11 SG1 FLY ROLLER COMAU", 15],
    ["CPU2A MESA ENTRADA BONDER ABB", 12]]


Array = Array.map(a => a.map(i => typeof i === 'number' ? Number(Math.round(i * 100) / 100) : i))

console.log(Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### No utilice como nombre de variables las palabras reservadas, funciones, objetos y clases nativas

Se debe evitar declarar variables que tengan como nombre las palabras reservadas, objetos, funciones o clases nativas de JavaScript.

Es decir, en lugar de declararlo así:

```js
var Array = [
  // Valores
];
```

Declárela de la siguiente manera:

```js
var array = [
  // Valores
];
```

Y podemos comprobar que el objeto `Array` existe escribiendo la siguiente líneas:

```js
console.log( Array );
```

Dado que `Array` es un objeto nativo de JavaScript que estás sobrescribiendo; cuyas consecuencias podrían llevar al programa a producir resultados inesperados.

Por ejemplo, vamos a citar dos (02) ejemplos para explicar por qué no deben declararse de la primera forma.

Sobrescribiremos el objeto `Array` de JavaScript y probaremos sus resultados en la consola:

```js
// Si se declara una variable con el nombre Array
var Array = [
  // Valores
];

// Devolverá TypeError: Array is not a function
console.log(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Se pudo observar que al ejecutar el código devuelve `TypeError: Array is not a function`, porque el objeto `Array` fue sobrescrito **como variable de tipo array**. Sin embargo, si en lugar de declararla de la forma anterior se declara como:

```js
var array = [
  // Valores
];

console.log(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Obtenemos el resultado esperado, que es `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, dado que no se ha sobrescrito el objeto.

Ten en cuenta que esto apenas es un ejemplo de las tantas que pueden presentarse para producir resultados inesperados en el programa cuando se declaran variables de la forma descrita en el primer ejemplo de esta publicación.

### Ahora vamos al redondeo

El siguiente ejemplo tomado de tu pregunta (incluye comentarios explicativos):

```js
var Array = [
  ["MAQUINA", "MIN"],
  ["CABINA EXTRACCION DISTANCIALES", 292.6333333333333],
  ["CPU6 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB SELLADO1 COMAU", 36.63333333333333],
  ["CPU10 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB HORNO ESM1 IZCOMAU", 30],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG5 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG8 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU1 GR11 SG1 FLY ROLLER COMAU", 15],
  ["CPU2A MESA ENTRADA BONDER ABB", 12]
];

// Funciona cuando se utiliza:
var Array = Array.map(value => {
  return value.map(value => {
    return isNaN(value) ? value : Math.round(value);
  });
});

console.log(Array);
```

Funciona, pero como se mencionó anteriormente en esta publicación; sobrescribe la clase `Array` y eso no se aconseja. En su lugar puede utilizar:

```js
var array = [
  ["MAQUINA", "MIN"],
  ["CABINA EXTRACCION DISTANCIALES", 292.6333333333333],
  ["CPU6 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB SELLADO1 COMAU", 36.63333333333333],
  ["CPU10 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB HORNO ESM1 IZCOMAU", 30],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG5 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG8 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU1 GR11 SG1 FLY ROLLER COMAU", 15],
  ["CPU2A MESA ENTRADA BONDER ABB", 12]
];

// Que también funciona:
var array = array.map(value => {
  return value.map(value => {
    return isNaN(value) ? value : Math.round(value);
  });
});

console.log(array);
```

Ya que produce el mismo resultado que el anterior, pero sin sobrescribir el objeto `Array`.

### Explicando el redondeo numérico dentro de un `array`

De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

> El método **map()** crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

Es decir, si se tiene:

```js
var array = [1.3322, 3.223, 5.33465];

// Podríamos obtener: [1, 3, 5], si se define así:
array = array.map( value =>
  isNaN( value ) ? value : Math.round(value)
);

console.log( array );
```

Obtenemos `[1, 3, 5]`, que es el valor redondeado como resultado de la utilización de los método **[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)** y **[Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round)**

Donde:

```js
isNaN(value) ? value : Math.round(value);
```

Es el operador ternario que evalúa si `value` no es numérico, de lo contraro, redondea su valor. Pero como tienes un array de dos dimensiones se podría utilizar así:

```js
var array = array.map(value => {
  return value.map(value => {
    return isNaN(value) ? value : Math.round(value);
  });
});
```

O también de esta manera sin el uso de las llaves y la palabra reservada **return**:

```js
var array = array.map(value =>
  value.map(value => (isNaN(value) ? value : Math.round(value)))
);
```

**IMPORTANTE:**

La función `isNaN()` significa literalmente *Is Not a Number*, que en español significa *No es un número*. Por lo tanto, como es una función de tipo *booleano* solo devuelve **true** o **false**. Puede utilizar también el método **isNaN()** del objeto **Number**.

Una forma de utilizarlo y no la única sería:

```js
if (isNaN(value)) {
  //  Si no es un número se ejecutan las
  // instrucciones acá
}
```

### Consultar fuentes

Puede consultar las siguientes fuentes:

- [Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).
- [isNaN() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN)
- [Number.isNaN() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN)
- [Math.round() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round)

Answer (score 0):

**Opción 1**

Para poder acceder a los números debemos visualizar que:

- Tu estructura es una matriz
- al menos en esta respuesta requieres mas de un `for of` para iterar dentro de la matriz y luego dentro de cada vector
- Si lo que deseas es redondear solo los números, entonces puedes en un condiconal indicarle que te aplique dicha operación de sobre aquellos cuyo `typeof` sea igual a `number`
- Para redondear se usa la función `round()` ya que `toFixed(parámetro)` es para indicarle cuantos decimales tomar después del símbolo de `.`

**Propuesta de solución**

```js
var vector = [
  ["MAQUINA", "MIN"],
  ["CABINA EXTRACCION DISTANCIALES", 292.6333333333333],
  ["CPU6 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB SELLADO1 COMAU", 36.63333333333333],
  ["CPU10 GR3 SG1 TRP TRB HORNO ESM1 IZCOMAU", 30],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG5 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU11 GR01 SG8 MESA ELEVADORA COMAU", 21],
  ["CPU1 GR11 SG1 FLY ROLLER COMAU", 15],
  ["CPU2A MESA ENTRADA BONDER ABB", 12]
]


for (elemento of vector) {
  for (numero of elemento) {
    (typeof numero === "number") ? (console.log(Math.round(numero))) : (console.log(numero))
  }
}
```

Comment: En un function anterior que uso para filtrar los vacios le agrege una de las soluciones pero no funciona.      var Nuevadata = Nuevadata.filter(function (arrayInterno) {
          return !arrayInterno.every(function (elemento) {
           if (typeof elemento === "number") {
               Math.round(elemento);
            }
            return elemento === "";
          });
      }); creo que esta mal ubicado el if

Comment: Personalmente no veo necesaria tanta *vuelta* para lo que se pretende, por ejemplo si ya estamos usando filter entonces veo innesario usar el método `every` pues al menos la idea que planteo es que el primer método que menciono nos genere un *vector* nuevo con aquellos elementos que sea numéricos ignorando a los demás

Comment: si pero no necesito un vector nuevo, solo requiero redondear los valores que tiene array existente. como los valores que recibo aveces son vacios yo elimino los vacios en esa funcion. pense agregarle a esa funcion tu solucion.

Comment: Entonces opino que de las 2 *soluciones* que aporto tal vez te sea mas ùtil la primera pues no genera un vector nuevo, trabaja sobre los valores del que ya existe y ahi mismo sobre esos elementos genera el resultado esperado